# Would reading/writing a file take the same time as moving the file?

Tags: c#, file, text

I need to make modifications to a textfile and keep the original intact.  Right now I am using a reader/writer and reading the file and then writing it back sans the modifications.

Unfortunately the text files are huge, ~2gb and are taking about an hour to complete (as the text files are on a network drive).

Would using the file.Move be faster than reading/writing?  For example, move the textfiles to local machine, do the modifications, then move it back?

Or, make a copy of the original and go through and modify it that way, instead of having to read/write?

My current code :

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output)) 
        { 
            //go through the whole txt file
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //gets the line
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (!modification case goes here))
                {
                    writer.Write(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried copying the file to your local machine and then back again? That will give you a baseline time that modifying the file locally will cost time wise. If the copying to and fro approaches 1 hour, then you're unlikely to realise many benefits from doing the modifications locally.

Comment: Where is the performance hit? If it's not on line = reader.ReadLine(); then location of the file doesn't matter, and I'm guessing the bottleneck would be your modification check. If ReadLine(); is your bottleneck I don't think moving the file locally and then back would help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will test those out right now and report back.

Comment: Is it possible for multiple clients to access this file over the network? If yes, some sort of a locking solution would be needed to ensure you can modify the file safely. Also, the obvious points: 1) if anyhow possible, split the file into smaller chunks. 2) Switch to 1GbE equipment (not expensive anymore), 3) install the app/service on the networked machine directly, 4) switch to SMB/iSCSI which would allow you to work with the file using memory-mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With attached network drives it's always faster to copy file locally, do whatever and copy it back. This way you use caching and fetch ahead (pre-caching) which is implemented at hardware level of the disk drive. Network throughput is always limited to average formula of Network_T_Rate / 10 expressed in Megabytes-per-second. So, for example, if you have 100T, as most of corporation networks, you'll get ~10Mb/s no matter read or write, as the disk on the other end is faster than network. In other words, your bottleneck is network.